# Change value at columns when finding values at column on the right for multiple pairs of columns without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this

```
+------+---+-------+---+-----+---+
| 2.80 | 5 | 45.02 | 2 | 0.2 | 2 |
| 3.40 | 1 | 34.21 | 2 | 1.2 | 2 |
| 5.84 | 2 | 98.10 | 2 | 3.4 | 5 |
| 3.85 | 4 | 73.10 | 5 | 2.3 | 5 |
| 2.10 | 5 | 32.12 | 1 | 0.3 | 4 |
+------+---+-------+---+-----+---+
```

And I want to change the value at the columns 1, 3 and 5 to `NaN` every time the value at the column immediately at right is equal to 4 or 5:

```
+------+---+-------+---+-----+---+
| NaN  | 5 | 45.02 | 2 | 0.2 | 2 |
| 3.40 | 1 | 34.21 | 2 | 1.2 | 2 |
| 5.84 | 2 | 98.10 | 2 | NaN | 5 |
| NaN  | 4 | NaN   | 5 | NaN | 5 |
| NaN  | 5 | 32.12 | 1 | NaN | 4 |
+------+---+-------+---+-----+---+
```

For example, at row 1, column 2, the value is 5, so row 1, column 1 must be changed to`NaN`.

I can do it with a loop, but once my data is really big I'm losing a lot of time on it. I would like to save time doing it without a loop, but I'm failing on it.

Comment: Is your data a `table` or cell array or what? Please provide the data in a format that allows us to recreate it in matlab

Comment: It's a matrix, I updated at the first line! @Suever

Comment: How do you have dates in a matrix alongside numbers?

Comment: It is not a matrix, matrices cannot have mixed data types.

Comment: The dates are in a separated datetime vector. I will take them out for consistent question. @Suever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate all `4` and `5` values with `ismember` and then `circshift` the resulting boolean to the left and replace with `NaN`

```
bool = ismember(data, [4 5]);

shifted = circshift(bool, [0 -1]);

data(shifted) = NaN;
```

Or as one line if you want

```
data(circshift(ismember(data, [4 5]), [0 -1])) = NaN;
```

This will cause values in the last column to be a `NaN` if the first column contains a 4 or 5. If you don't want that to happen you could do something like this:

```
to_be_nan = ismember(data(:,2:end), [4 5]);
to_be_nan(:,end+1) = false;

data(to_be_nan) = NaN;
```

Comment: With loop:
Elapsed time is 2.664541 seconds.
Without loop:
Elapsed time is 0.047656 seconds.

Comment: I made it a little bit different from your answer and I'm going to paste it here in case some one else need this knowledge. bool =ismember(data(:,[2 4 6]), [4 5]); temp = false(size(data)); temp(:,[1 3 5])=bool; data(temp) = NaN;